# Linear mixed models with repeated gain scores in a natural experiment

Tags: mixed-model, pre-post-comparison, observational-study

**Background**: I‘m working on a dataset that contains observational data from questionnaires referring to a natural experiment. People were asked weekly whether they received an unexpected message (X), how much they slept (Z), and about their well-being (Y). Y and Z were measured in another sub-survey, so for each observation of X, I merged in the closest observation for Y and Z before and after X to get a pre/post measure. Each row now contains the user id, the value for x,z, and the corresponding pre and post values for Y. As central assumptions for adjusting the post value with the pre value to control for the pre-measure are not met (groups have not been randomized at baseline), I opted in for the use of gain/change/difference scores (https://homes.ori.org/keiths/Tips/Stats_GainScores.html) as the outcome of my regression Ydiff ~ X*Z, where Ydiff = Post - Pre.

**The question**: The number of observations varies between people: Some people did participate more than others, resulting in multiple change scores per person; others have only one change score available. Does it make sense to model the potentially nested structure for each user with a random intercept? Can the occurrence of multiple change scores even be called nested? I really have no idea how to continue here at the moment. Thank you all!

This is what the data looks like:

| ID | x | z | pre | post | ydiff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 356 | not received | 4.2590 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 356 | received | 5.6615 | 1 | 5 | 4 |
| 1088 | received | 8.8172 | 5 | 5 | 0 |
| 1089 | not received | 5.0027 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 1089 | did not check | 5.3050 | 2 | 5 | 3 |

Code to reproduce in R:

```
n <- 4000
data_frame <- transform(
  data.frame(
    ID = sample(rep(sample(1:2000, 500, replace = FALSE), each = 4), n, replace = TRUE),
    x = sample(c("received", "not received", "did not check"), n, replace = TRUE),
    z = runif(n, 4, 10),
    pre = sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE),
    post = sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE)
  ),
  ydiff = post - pre
)
```

Comment: How does the `y` in your example data relate to `pre` and/or `post`? From your explanation I'd assume one of these to match but that's not the case. You should almost certainly model repeated measures though, because it's unlikely that the outcomes within one person are as variable as those between different people (assumption of independent errors likely violated).

Comment: You're entirely right, pre/post and Y indeed match. Fixed it. I just tried to model the user level as a random intercept, but the random effects variance is estimated zero. Seems like empirically there's no nested structure? The df contains around 70,000 observations, should be enough to reliably estimate the random effects variance if present...

Comment: I think you shouldn't use the difference scores as the outcome if you use multilevel regression (mixed model), just as you wouldn't use difference scores in RM-ANOVA. You should use the actual pre-post scores and add a random intercept of participant. (It may still turn out that random intercept variance is zero, though). Different people having different number of observations shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I agree with @Sointu,  would not use change scores at all.  I think what you have is a doubly nested model, but I haven't seen this exact structure before and I am not sure of that. But it's a place to start looking. A long time ago, I did see somewhat similar models discussed on SAS-L by Dale McLerran. But a) You are clearly an R user and b) I'm not sure how to find those posts.  SAS-L is defunct.  But they probably can be found.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, much appreciated. I'll have a look into the discussion on doubly nested models.

Comment: @PeterFlom in what sense is this "doubly nested" ? I'm not familiar with that term (unless you mean that one factor is nested in another, and I don't see how that is the case here). My cursory reading of the question leads me to think it's a fairly standard repeated measures scenario. I'm probably missing something !

Comment: @RobertLong I am not sure either!  Maybe you aren't missing anything and I am seeing things.

Comment: @PeterFlom LOL :)   Thank you. I've got a rather long comment which I will post as an answer, thanks again :)

Answer (score 5):

This is more of a comment than an answer, but I just wanted to add to what was said in the comments to the question, noting that change scores are known to be problematic. For example see Tennant et al (2022):

Tennant PWG, Arnold KF, Ellison GTH, Gilthorpe MS. Analyses of 'change scores' do not estimate causal effects in observational data. Int J Epidemiol. 2022 Oct 13;51(5):1604-1615. doi: 10.1093/ije/dyab050. PMID: 34100077; PMCID: PMC9557845.

> Change-score analyses do not provide meaningful causal-effect estimates unless the baseline outcome variable is a 'competing exposure' for the effect of the exposure on the outcome at follow-up. Where the baseline outcome is a confounder or mediator, change-score analyses evaluate obscure estimands, which may diverge substantially in magnitude and direction from the total and direct causal effects.

> Conclusion: Future observational studies that seek causal-effect estimates should avoid analysing change scores and adopt alternative analytical strategies.

From what I can tell about the situation, a fairly standard repeated measures mixed model, with random intercepts for subjects(`ID`) should be appropriate here.